# Re-gain access to memory in a thread in Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, multithreading

In Ruby, is there a way to spin off a thread, store a variable inside, and then come back later, access the thread, and access the variable inside the thread?

Basically I need to store resources in some common memory pool. These can't be serialized or stored in Memcached. The problem I am facing is that I want to persist an FTP connection object across AJAX calls. I need to regain access to the connection object on the server-side end of multiple AJAX calls.

Comment: Any reason not to use `Queue` class? http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Queue.html

Comment: I need this variable accessible between AJAX requests. It's a resource, so it can't be stored in something like Memcached.

Comment: A database? A cookie? Session info?  I don't think you are describing your limitations well enough for someone to answer the question.

Comment: Yes! I'm using Rails. The problem I am facing is that I want to persist an FTP connection object across AJAX calls. I need to regain access to the connection object on the server-side end of multiple AJAX calls.

Comment: Maybe take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1095714/storing-objects-in-a-session-in-rails

Comment: @Kyle Heironimus - Unfortunately, you can't store an FTP connection in the session.

Comment: We do something similar to this, but with a separate app.  It loads the rails environment, so has access to all the models and such, but it just runs on its own.  If you figure out a better way to do this, I'd like to know.

Comment: How are you serving this application?  The problem I see here is that if you have more than one process serving requests (as is the case in most Rails app servers I know of), you have no guarantee that AJAX call 2 is handled by the same process that handled AJAX call 1.

Comment: I think I'm going to just have a C/C++ daemon run in the background that creates connections and acts as a proxy on behalf of my Rails app. My Rails app will communicate with the daemon. Shouldn't be a problem, as I already have an adapter class I've created that my Rails app depends on (FtpConnectionAdapter), so I'll just need to change the guts of that class to use the daemon, and my program won't care.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up making this work using global variables (eg. $my_global). I have a ConnectionPooler singleton class which manages connections stored in a hash. Easy as pie.