# How to store ActiveRecord object in session using Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, session, web

I'm building an Shopping Cart for my site and I having one trouble with rails session and
ActiveRecord Objects:

Shopping Cart is actually one Order object with some OrderItems.

After add Order object to session, Dalli started raise this exception:

```
Marshalling error for key 'sessions:9e67886e826819a3213df4f4c89db6e0': can't dump hash with default proc
You are trying to cache a Ruby object which cannot be serialized to memcached.
/home/rodrigo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@netsabe-ecommerce/gems/dalli-2.1.0/lib/dalli/server.rb:277:in `dump'
    /home/rodrigo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@netsabe-ecommerce/gems/dalli-2.1.0/lib/dalli/server.rb:277:in `serialize'
    /home/rodrigo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@netsabe-ecommerce/gems/dalli-2.1.0/lib/dalli/server.rb:164:in `set'
    /home/rodrigo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@netsabe-ecommerce/gems/dalli-2.1.0/lib/dalli/server.rb:48:in `request'
    /home/rodrigo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@netsabe-ecommerce/gems/dalli-2.1.0/lib/dalli/options.rb:18:in `block in request'
    /home/rodrigo/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
    /home/rodrigo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@netsabe-ecommerce/gems/dalli-2.1.0/lib/dalli/options.rb:17:in `request'
    /home/rodrigo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@netsabe-ecommerce/gems/dalli-2.1.0/lib/dalli/client.rb:251:in `perform'
    /home/rodrigo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@netsabe-ecommerce/gems/dalli-2.1.0/lib/dalli/client.rb:120:in `set'
    /home/rodrigo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@netsabe-ecommerce/gems/dalli-2.1.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/session/dalli_store.rb:50:in `set_session'
```

Googling, I found that ActiveRecord can not be stored on session.

So, how is the best way to store this objects on session?
I will have to implement serialize/deserialize methods for these classes?

Thank you!

**EDIT 1:**

Remembering that Order object isn't persisted yet!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Storing objects in the session is a bad idea.
[Storing Objects in a Session in Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1095714/storing-objects-in-a-session-in-rails)
Better to store the `id` of the object so you can always check if the object in on the latest state.

Comment: Ok, but Order object is not persisted on database yet.

Comment: @Rodrigo: It doesn't have to be persisted, you'll get a default proc pretty much as soon as you think about an AR object: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6392704/479863

Comment: but that will always run the database query.. if i store object to session i will save that queries .. ?!