# Ensure that each instance of a model in Rails exists at most once in memory

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Suppose I have a `User` class in my ActiveRecord model, and I store the user object inside a session when the user logs in. (i.e. `session[:user] = user`)

At some point in my code I might load the same user from the database and update it.

```
user = User.where(happy: false).first
user.happy = true
user.save
```

But then the user in the session is not up to date because `session[:user]` is a reference to another instance of User in memory.

If ActiveRecord query methods loaded instances of `User` from memory if possible (possibly with the ObjectSpace), this would fix the problem, but in order to avoid the [XY problem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem), what is a better way of approaching this problem?
Is the best method to repeatedly refresh every object in the session when each controller runs? Should I avoid storing objects in the session in favor of object ID's?

Comment: There used to be an optional identity map for ActiveRecord but ["Rails 4.0 has removed the identity map from Active Record, due to some inconsistencies with associations"](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/upgrading_ruby_on_rails.html#upgrading-from-rails-3-2-to-rails-4-0-active-record). I'd recommend against using the session like that, if you need a user somewhere, pass it on down the call chain or try to make sure that the user will only be used in the smallest possible scope.

Comment: Do you mean that you would recommend loading the user from the database when needed (by storing its id in the session, for example) rather than storing the object directly?

Comment: Or using the usual `current_user` method in your controllers. Then, if you suspect that someone has changed the underlying user behind your back, manually `reload` it. I only put ids in anything persistent and avoid hidden global variables (which is what `session` and even `current_user` really are) as much as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Storing objects in the session store is a [bad idea, as explained in this response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1095714/storing-objects-in-a-session-in-rails).

So you're right with your guess of storing ids instead, that's the right way of doing it.