# How can I allow users to choose the columns shown in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a model named `Employee` that has over a dozen fields making it impractical to display all fields at once. I would like to allow users to choose which columns are displayed by using either a multiple select box or a list of checkboxes, the result of which would ideally be stored in memory, not in the model since nothing will be saved long term, and be accessible for a loop to display the appropriate columns.

A sample of the view might be like so:

```
<% for employee in @employees %>
  <tr>
    <% for col in col_list %>
      <td><%= employee.col %></td>
    <% end %>
  </tr>
<% end %>
```

where `col_list` is the list of columns selected by the user.

Comment: Do you want the preferences saved per user session or per instance of the particular page?

Comment: Really just per particular page. It'd be for just one time reports.

Comment: Are you using a form to allow users to select what they want to see on the report that is generated? Then "submit" action executes the report generation?

Comment: Currently I'm showing all of the information and using Ransack to allow the users to filter the results.

Comment: Okay. I'm not familiar with Ransack, so I don't think I can help you. If you were not using Ransack, but rather using an input form, my advice would have been to use the params hash data from the input form to control conditional processing (which columns are to be displayed) in your view code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A better approach might be to output all the columns server side and do the filtering with javascript in the client. There are several libraries for this such as [jQuery Datatables](http://datatables.net/).

You can combine this with a preferences model which is [persisted to the session](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1095714/storing-objects-in-a-session-in-rails) or [Redis](http://www.sitepoint.com/rails-model-caching-redis/) instead of the main RDBMS if you want to remember the user prefs.

(Yes, you can use models for objects not stored in the DB. It gives you all the rails awesomeness of validations, form and param binding etc.)

Comment: Basically if you do the filtering  serverside the user would need to reload the page to get anything which is not already there.

Comment: I'm not really worried about server load in this application. It's a really small application with not a lot of data and probably 20 users max.

Comment: Its more about user experience than server load. Using javascript to filter it gives the user instant control feedback vs waiting for the page to reload. Also you don't have deal with filtering the columns in Rails. There are several javascripts libs which can  do all this out of the box.

Comment: I think I found what I'm looking for in [jQuery Datatables ColVis option.](http://datatables.net/extensions/colvis/) Would you recommend using the [jquery-datatables-rails](https://github.com/rweng/jquery-datatables-rails) gem?

Comment: I don't have much experience with either of them. I would look at the activity on github, quality of the documentation, code and tests suite.

Comment: The repo I linked to was used in a RailsCast and was quite easy to implement and add extensions such as ColVis and TableTools. Thanks for showing me this! Just what I needed!

Answer (score 1):

As it is described, there is nothing particularly complicated in this feature.

If you have the users logged in somewhere, you can store a serialized list of columns somewhere in a preference for the user. The list of columns should probably be sanitized to avoid showing private columns.

If the user is not logged in, or you want a less persistent approach, simply store the list in a cookie.

If the list is not set (aka the cookie is empty), set it to a default or just render a default list of attributes.

Comment: Would this be the easiest route if each user may want to change the settings regularly?